# Building latest nightly webkit release for Android platform

Tags: android, webkit

We are developing an Android app that requires some new featues in the latest webkit.

Since most android phones still have old webkit versions, we'd like to bundle the latest nightly webkit release within our app.

But we cannot find webkit nightly release for android platform. It seems we have to build from nightly webkit source code.

If you know where we can download the nightly webkit build for Android platform, please let us know. Or if you know how to build it from the nightly release source code, please kindly point me to the right direction. thanks!!